# How to make CGSize Hashable

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make CGSize hashable, should it be

```
extension CGSize: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(NSCoder.string(for: self).hashValue)
    }
}
```

or

```
extension CGSize: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(NSCoder.string(for: self))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of them. Basically don't mix Objective-C `NSObject` related hash pattern with Swift's own `Hashable` implementation. `NSCoder` is only for subclasses of `NSObject`.

`CGSize` contains `width` and `height`, hash that

```
extension CGSize: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(width)
        hasher.combine(height)
    }
}
```